# Using protobuf net with DictionaryBase

Tags: protobuf-net

I'm new to using protobuf and have an issue trying to serialize a class that inherits from Dictionary. Additional properties are not being serialized.
As an examle I have this class

```
[ProtoContract]
  public class InheritDictionary: Dictionary<string,string>
  {
    private int _myInt;


    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public int MyInt
    {
      get
      {
        return _myInt;
      }
      set
      {
        _myInt = value;
      }
    }

  }
```

When I serialize the MyInt property is not included.
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The protobuf specification has no notion of collection objects. On the wire you **only** get the contained elements - the collection does not feature *at all* in the data. Because of this, there is nowhere to store any properties of something that is a list - and dictionaries are essentially lists (of key/value pairs).

At the DTO layer, I would say: don't inherit collections. *Encapsulate* collections instead. Have an object that *has* a dictionary and *has* the extra properties.

Comment: Thanks Marc, I thought that's what I'd have to do. Nice to get confirmation that you're not doing something wrong.